# When I render an image everything is black and white. How do I fix this?

Tags: rendering

Everything appears black and white:

[image: render]

How do I fix this?

Comment: a very bright light sun (or point) light and no other sources will make that extreme contrast... but to know for sure you'd need to edit your question and post more information...

Comment: Do you have any composite nodes? Materials? What render engine are you using? Or if possible, could you upload your .blend?

Comment: I took out all the lamps and put a new one in set the energy to one and it looks the same.

Comment: It does not change even if there is no sun lamps.

Comment: Also, this is the first frame on an animation, when i render the animation the only frame it will render is the first frame. It will only render the first frame if I'm rendering it as an image too.

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/download/2q7suez37d15yki/Blend1.zip

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You probably have your render set to "BW"(which stands for Black and White), instead of "RGB"(Which stands for Red,Green,Blue). It needs to be selected to "RGB" in order to be in color.

Comment: I have the RBG set, but i dont have a RBGA. Im new and dont know most things about blender.